# Сформулировать регулярное выражение

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Есть вопрос. Входные данные такие:

```
var reg = /([www]*\.+[a-z0-9]+\.+[a-z]*\S)|(\S+\:\/\/[a-z0-9\:\/_.?=&%+A-Z-]*\S)/igm;
```

На примере текста:

> 3) В EV рядом с СДМ должна быть иконка при клике на которую происходит открытие соответствующего EV новым слоем http://prntscr.com/cl6rer
>   Иконка http://fontawesome.io/icon/arrow-circle-right/
>   Размер и цвет иконки http://prntscr.com/cl6s5h
>
> 4) В ленте активности все URL должны быть в виде ссылок - при клике переход по ссылке в новой вкладке

http://prntscr.com/cr001w

http://prntscr.com/cr02ue

Пробема в том, что убираются переводы строк. Я что-то не учёл в регулярном выражении?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема у Вас связана не с регулярным выражением (хотя и в нём есть проблемы, но они второстепенны), а с тем, что Вы используете функцию `jQuery.text()`, которая игнорирует переносы строк, оформленные тэгом `<br/>` в итоге на вход регулярному выражению поступает текст без переносов строк.

В живом примере регулярного выражения можно увидеть, что оно корректно находит ссылки
https://regex101.com/r/54FFNT/1

В живом тесте функции `jQuery.text()` можно увидеть, что она не учитывает `<br/>`:

```js
$( document ).ready( function(){
 $( "#result" ).html( $("#source").text() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Source</b>
<div id="source">
test, <br/> sf
sdf <br/> sdf
</div>
<b>Result</b>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```